# Hibernate Specific DDL Generation

Tags: hibernate

i'm using hibernate schema export tool. As I'm using MySql as RDBMS provider, i wonder if i can place specific mysql parameters somewhere ,like using collation utf8_bin ...

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with [gid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31480/gid). Hibernate allows you to define own or change standard dialect that will have an impact for resulting DMS. Some details can be found [in the article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2008/jw-08-hibernate-annotations.html). We are using the approach for generating specific parameters for Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle and other supported databases.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, there isn't a way to do this. Hibernate only reconmends that you use the schema export tool as a starting point thus there isn't any obvious hook points where you can add db specific stuff to the create statements.

Possible work arounds:

1. create an `import.sql` on the classpath, the export will run this after all of the generated statements, you might be able to run some alter table style stuff to make the changes you need
2. there might some milage in extending the mysql dialect to add the options that you need. I've not looked in to it to see if there are enough hook points to change things like the collation sequence, but it's about as good as your going to get I'm afraid.